# Dealing with Download Listener in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview, android-permissions, android-download-manager

Hello I'm new to Android Studio and I'm dealing with the DownloadListener in my webView in order to download the files which has been uploaded on the web page, basically you can say a file in pdf format,however I tried my level best to find the error but couldn't found one.The error lies in the moment we click on some downloadable link on the webpage it shows error which goes like that:

```
02-05 22:47:29.425 3531-3531/myapp.hp.com.abhivyakti E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: myapp.hp.com.abhivyakti, PID: 3531
   java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write to /storage/emulated/0/Download/download: Neither user 10059 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
       at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
       at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1231)
       at android.app.DownloadManager.enqueue(DownloadManager.java:946)
       at myapp.hp.com.abhivyakti.Notification.NotifyFragment$3.onDownloadStart(NotifyFragment.java:95)
       at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onDownloadStart(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:884)
       at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$MyHandler.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:112)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My code for the Activity is given below:

```
public class NotifyFragment extends Fragment {

  public NotifyFragment() {
      // Required empty public constructor
  }

  private WebView webView;
  private ProgressBar pb;
  private ConnectivityManager cManager;
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // Inflate the layout for this fragment
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notify, container, false);
      webView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.notifywebView);
      pb = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.notifyprogressBar);

      cManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      NetworkInfo nInfo = cManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
      if (nInfo == null) {
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
          builder.setMessage("No Internet Connection")
                  .setTitle("Oops!!")
                  .setIcon(R.drawable.caution);
          builder.setCancelable(false);
          builder.setPositiveButton("Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/d/12u6jzoY8zB11valB2FwMyrf0HcWDnOvCkokzggNu1bA/edit?usp=sharing");
              }
          });
          AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
          alert.show();
      }else {
          webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/d/12u6jzoY8zB11valB2FwMyrf0HcWDnOvCkokzggNu1bA/edit?usp=sharing");
      }
      //getActivity().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
      getActivity().getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
      webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
          public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
              //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
              pb.setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

              // Return the app name after finish loading
              if (progress == 100) {
                  pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              } else {
                  pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              }
          }
      });
      webView.setWebViewClient(new mywebClient());
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/d/12u6jzoY8zB11valB2FwMyrf0HcWDnOvCkokzggNu1bA/edit?usp=sharing");
      webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
          public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                      String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                      long contentLength) {
              DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                      Uri.parse(url));
              request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
              request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
              request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");
              DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
              dm.enqueue(request);
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      });
      return view;
  }

  public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient {

      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          view.loadUrl(url);
          return true;
      }
  }
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
      if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
          webView.goBack();
          return true;
      }
      return onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
}
```

I will be thankful as it will help me to move forward and give the bug free app. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Two questions:

A) Did you add in your manifest the following permission?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

B) If you did and still does not work, what version is your Android device?

Comment: Thank you for the consideration. As I did that part of adding the same permission which you've mentioned it, but its giving me the same error. I've assigned the minimum used sdk to Jellybean i.e., 4.0.